# Simple Cute Blue Boxes

Tags: css

By any chance anyone know how the these cute blue boxes under "Browse Categories" are created? Is it simple css and javascript?

Once I know what they are called I can google something like "Cute Blue boxes generator" or something along those lines.

url with cute boxes:
http://vimeo.com/categories

Answer (score 1):

The majority of the styling is simply adding rounded corners to a light blue box. In CSS, a similar effect can be achieved (in modern browsers) with:

```
li {
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Note Vimeo simply uses an image as a background:

http://a.vimeocdn.com/images/categories/cat_browse_on.png

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple background image put there with CSS:

```
#cat_browse ul li.highlight {
    background: url(http://a.vimeocdn.com/images/categories/cat_browse_off.png);
}
```

[image: cute blue box]